# Script executes successfully in commandline but not as a cronjob

Tags: ruby, bash, cron

I've a bash script that runs a ruby script that fetches my twitter feeds.

```
## /home/username/twittercron

#!/bin/bash

cd /home/username/twitter
ruby twitter.rb friends
```

It runs successfully in command line.

```
/home/username/twittercron
```

But when I try to run it as a cronjob, it ran but wasn't able to fetch the feeds.

```
## crontab -e

*/15 * * * * * /home/username/twittercron
```

The script has been chmod +x. Not sure why it's as such. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ruby Version Manager (rvm) was causing the problem. I had to call the script in cron like this.

```
*/15 * * * * bash -c 'source /home/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm && /usr/bin/env ruby /home/username/twitter/twitter.rb friends'
```

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem for about a week now.  Thank you so much for this!

Comment: you may source your entire bashrc instead, assuming it sources rvm. `source $HOME/.bashrc && …`

Answer (score 9):

I think that can be done just by forcing bash to act as a login shell, so it sources .bashrc, etc.:

```
*/15 * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/home/username/twittercron'
```

[Here](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/09/07/rvm-and-cron-in-production) is an article about this.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good experience using http://github.com/javan/whenever

It uses a Ruby DSL to manage cron tasks and it handles setting all the environment magic.

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the absolute path to the executing command (or via env).

```
*/15 * * * * * /usr/bin/env sh /home/username/twittercron
```

Alternatively:

```
*/15 * * * * * /usr/bin/env ruby /home/username/twitter/twitter.rb friends
```

Comment: that's a bash script he is running.

Comment: What are you expecting as a result?  Does it write out to a file or database?  Or are you just waiting for the crontab's stdout to be system mailed to you?

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many `*`s in your crontab.

Answer (score 0):

check your mail and see if there's any error messages. Put some debugging in your bash script, eg `echo done>debug.log` at the last line and see if `debug.log` is created. remove the `## /home/username/twittercron` in your script and put `#!/bin/bash` on the first line.

```
*/15 * * * * * /bin/bash /home/username/twittercron
```

Comment: Instead of debug.log, try: `MAILTO=your@email.addy` (inside the crontab), then running `/bin/bash -x /home/username/twittercron` as the cron command. That will email the full trace at the end.

Comment: My /var/log/syslog & /var/log/cron.log shows that the command ran but no error thrown.