# Rake tasks from cron - uninitialized constant YAML::ENGINE

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

I am getting uninitialized constant YAML::ENGINE when running a rake task from cron since I upgraded my server to ruby 1.9.2.  I had the same error with the app but putting ...

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
```

in the boot.rb file fixed it.  If I run the task directly from the command line on my Ubuntu server it works fine, the server uses RVM.

However running a task from cron doesn't seem to pickup this fix, I have tried this ...

```
task :twitter, :needs => :environment do
  require 'yaml'
  YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
  @tweets = Property.updatetwitter
end
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you're running it under Ruby 1.9.2? Because while YAML::ENGINE exists in 1.9.2, it's not in 1.8.7. Check your Ruby version.

**UPDATE**

How to tell which Ruby version program is using from within the program:

```
puts `ruby -v`
```

Lame way how to enforce cron task to run under certain Ruby version (if server uses RVM):

```
rvm use 1.8.7; ...
```

Comment: I can't tell as it's running directly from cron, do you know how I can force the cron job into 1.9.2?

Comment: I updated the answer, but I don't have much experience with that so the proposed solution is lame, there's got to be better way. It's also quite possible that cron runs under different account, so it doesn't know about RVM and uses system ruby (/usr/bin/ruby or something) - in that case, reinstall ruby on your server.

Comment: Am trying out this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398722/script-executes-successfully-in-commandline-but-not-as-a-cronjob/2399118#2399118) which could be the way forward, big thanks @LukasStejskal